# non closable window in windows form using c#?

Tags: c#, .net

When I click a submit button on the windows form, it should throw up a popup window (asking for yes or no) which doesn't have a close (X) button even if we click wherever that popup window should blink for that response.

So how to do it?

Comment: @Anandkumar there's no sign of any exceptions in this question

Comment: CodeCaster popup window form appears with (X) button. so i can close it without answering i.e. yes or no. i need to close that window by answering only. now have u got my point???

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the Form's 'Closing' event, do some checks, and set e.Cancel to true if you would like to prevent the form from closing.

```
    private bool _incomplete;

    private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_incomplete)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

P.S. and next time, please search google before you post, this is not how StackOverflow works , you see.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
   MessageBox.Show("Test","abc",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```